# how to prevent re-use cookies of previous session using InAppBrowser( android)

Tags: javascript, react-native, inappbrowser

I'm using react-native-inappbrowser-reborn package, when I try to Signin, the last account I logged in with is automatically selected. There is no solution to prevent using previous session cookies??
I'm not able to choose an account

```
export const openGateWay = async (provider: string, navigation: any, dispatch: any, type: string) => {
    const deepLink = getDeepLink('')

    const url = `https://auth.noxaws.com//oauth2/authorize?identity_provider=${provider}&redirect_uri=${deepLink}&response_type=CODE&client_id=3ci277sn2mjed01mpgflfd7uf2&scope=aws.cognito.signin.user.admin&email&openid&phone&profile`


if (await InAppBrowser.isAvailable()) {
    await InAppBrowser.close();
        const result = await InAppBrowser.openAuth(url, deepLink, {
            showTitle: true,
            enableUrlBarHiding: true,
            enableDefaultShare: true,
            forceCloseOnRedirection: false,
        })
        if (result.type === 'success') {
            let code = result.url.split(':').map((pair) => pair.split('='))[1][1]

            code = code.replace('#', '').replace('#_', '').replace('_', '')
            usersServices.httpRequest({ code, redirectUri: deepLink }, 'auth/exchange-code', 'POST').then((response: any) => {
                if (response && response.AccessToken) {
                    if (response.IsNewUser) {
                        setTimeout(
                            () =>
                                navigation.navigate('SignupFinalization', {
                                    userToken: response.AccessToken,
                                    refreshToken: response.RefreshToken,
                                })
                                ,
                                200
                                )
                            } else {
                                if (type === 'signup') {
                                    navigation.navigate('Login', { screen: 'LoginForm' })
                                } else {
                                    AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', response.AccessToken)
                                    AsyncStorage.setItem('refreshToken', response.RefreshToken)
                                    dispatch({
                                        type: '@@user/LOGIN_USER',
                                        payload: { token: response.AccessToken, refreshToken: response.RefreshToken },
                                    })
                                    navigation.navigate('AppScreen', { screen: 'Home' })
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
    InAppBrowser.close()
}
```

Comment: on ios, there's an option `ephemeralWebSession: true` that should prevent re-use from the previous session if `openAuth` was used.... I would like to know android solution as well... though I am afrad this is something the user configures in the respective browser and you cannot simply force your behaviour through....

Comment: in my case I will probably go with signing the user out manually after successful token creation, which seems to be the easiest way